# Matching words in array of strings and returning new array with the matches and count

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

I am trying to take a list of words and compare each one. If the word is similar or a substring than it will return the count of how many words are alike. If none are found it will return -1.

When I run the code for input{similar, liar, not, knot , java}... output{not}, when should be output{[similar, liar], [knot, not]} count =2. But if I add these words it works, and I am not sure why. input : mass, as, hero, superhero, not output: as, hero count is = 2

```
public static List<String> stringMatching(String [] words){
        HashSet<String> temp = new HashSet<>();
        int n = words.length;
        int count = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            String currentWord = words[i];
            for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++) {
                String nextWord = words[j];
                if(currentWord.contains(nextWord)) {
                    temp.add(nextWord);
                    count++;
                }
                if(nextWord.contains(currentWord)) {
                    temp.add(currentWord);
                    count++;
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        return new ArrayList<String>(temp);

public static void main(String[] args){
   String[] words = {"mass", "as", "hero", "superhero", "not"};
        List<String> listM = stringMatching(words);
        for(String x: listM) {
            System.out.println(x+ " ");
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you define “similar”?

Comment: In your example, the word "liar" doesn't appear in the string "similar" exactly, so a substring won't match it; `"similar".contains("liar")` is false.

Comment: In your example of "should be output", the word "liar" is _not_ a substring of "similar", so as Bohemian asks, how do you define strings to be similar?

Comment: I was looking at similar as in similar characters...sorry probably be more like an anagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code outputs

```
2
as
hero
```

This is correct given your code. Take note that you are:

- Doing the matching given an Array of Strings
- Adding `nextWord` if said String contains or is contained within `currentWord`
- Printing `count`
- Returning a list with validated `nextWord`s
- Printing each String in the returned list.

The output you want, as I understand in your question, should look like

```
[mass, as] 
[superhero, hero]
count = 2
```

for the Strings in the code. For the String in your question, the output should be `[knot, not] count = 1` because similar does not contain liar.

One way to generate that output is to print the words first and return the count value.

```java
    public static int stringMatching(String [] words){
        int n = words.length;
        int count = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
            String currentWord = words[i];
            for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++) {
                String nextWord = words[j];
                if(currentWord.contains(nextWord)) {
                    System.out.format("[%s, %s]\n", currentWord, nextWord);
                    count++;
                }
                if(nextWord.contains(currentWord)) {
                    System.out.format("[%s, %s]\n", nextWord, currentWord);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count == 0 ? -1 : count; //if no strings matched, return -1 instead of 0. 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] words = {"mass", "as", "hero", "superhero", "not"};
        int count = stringMatching(words);
        System.out.format("Count = %d", count);
    }
```

With this code, the output is

```
[mass, as]
[superhero, hero]
Count = 2
```

And for the words in your question, the result is

```
[knot, not]
Count = 1
```

Comment: So for [knot not] it needs to also show [similar, liar] if i wanted that would I have to check each character? Like liar is consider an anagram of similar.

Comment: If that's the case then you would need an additional algorithm like [Levenshtein's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to look for **similar** Strings. That being said, yes: You could look character by character, but how would you know if the _i_ of _liar_ is the first or the second _i_ of _similar_? _Rail_ then would "contain" _liar_ too. You need to think of those cases.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of doing a method to get a list of anagrams and compare to the original list and then save that to a new array the results. But I will look a Levenshteins distance and check that out.